Topology for the complex numbers endowed with different notions of convergence
I was wondering what does the topology of the complex numbers look like if it is endowed with different notions of convergence. My question came to follow from the idea of Cesáro mean convergence, Abel summability and  Ramanujan summation. What I mean with that is the following:
First, say that a sequence $s: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ converges to $x$ in the prescribed manner if and only if the summation of the $w$ coefficients $w_i = s_i-s_{i-1}$ (for $i>0$) and with $w_0=s_0$ converges in the sense prescribed (to say that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} w_i = x$ with the assumed notion of convergence). Then, my questions are the following:

If I associate with each convergent sequence its limit according to this definition, will this be a topological space when (for example) declaring a set to be closed when it contains all of its limit points?
What will this topological space look like with respect to the usual topology of $\mathbb{C}$? What will the open and closed sets be?

Note: I found it interesting because then I would be able to make more sense out of different notions of convergence by understanding their topology.

To answer what I think is the real question here: There is no topology on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = x$ in this topology if and only if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} = x$ in the standard topology.  To see this, take the example of $a_n := (-1)^n$.  This has Cesaro limit 0; however, it also has a subsequence $a_{2n} = 1$ with Cesaro limit 1, and a subsequence $a_{2n+1} = -1$ with Cesaro limit -1.  This conflicts with the fact that in a topological space, any subsequence of a convergent sequence must have the same limit.
The same counterexample works for Abel summation and Ramanujan summation: for Abel summation, for instance, $\lim_{x\to 1^-} (a_0 + (a_1 - a_0) x + (a_2 - a_1) x^2 + \cdots) = \lim_{x\to 1^-} (1 - \frac{2x}{1+x}) = 0$, whereas the Abel summation limit of the subsequence $a_{2n} = 1$ would be $\lim_{x\to 1^-} 1 = 1$.

Since the OP asked a slightly different question, let me mention that this example also shows, if we define a set to be closed iff it contains all limits of sequences in the set under these altered notions of convergence, we won’t get a topology since finite unions of closed sets may not be closed. Indeed, ${1}$ and ${-1}$ are both closed, but ${1, -1}$ is not.
